# Two correlated brownian motions

Tags: monte-carlo, correlation, brownian-motion

Is it true *([see here](https://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2009/rapporter09/odelman_torbjorn_09020.pdf), footnote 2, p.22 / p.14, without proof)* that we can obtain two discretized brownian motions $W_t^1, W_t^2$ **with correlation $\rho$** by doing

$$d W_t^1 \sim \mathcal N(0,\sqrt{dt})$$

$$d W_t^2 = \rho\, d W_t^1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} dZ_t$$ with $dZ_t \sim \mathcal N(0,\sqrt{dt})$ ?

If this is true, we could easily simulate them in Python by doing:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000000; dt = 0.01; rho = 0.8
dW1 = np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), n)
dW2 = rho * dW1 + np.sqrt(1 - rho **2) * np.random.normal(0, np.sqrt(dt), n)
W1 = np.cumsum(dW1)
W2 = np.cumsum(dW2)
plt.plot(W1)
plt.plot(W2)
plt.show()
```

**Is this correct?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to correct the formula to:
$$
W_t^2 = \rho W_t^1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z_t, 
$$
where $Z_t$ is a BM independent of $W_t^1$
If you calculate the variance and the covariance, then you see that it is true:
$$
V[W_t^1] = t
$$
and
$$
V[W_t^2] = \rho^2 V[W_t^1] + (1-\rho^2) V[Z_t] = \rho^2 t + (1-\rho^2) t = t,
$$
which is the desired variance.

For the covariance you get
$$
Cov[W_t^1,W_t^2] =  \rho Cov[W_t^1, W_t^1] + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Cov[W_t^1, Z_t] 
$$
which gives (because $Cov[W_t^1, W_t^1] = V[W_t^1]$ and by indpenence of $W_t^1$ and $Z_t$:
$$
Cov[W_t^1,W_t^2] =  \rho t + 0,
$$
and noting that $\sqrt{V[W_t^1]} = \sqrt{V[W_t^2]}  = \sqrt{t}$ we get
$$
Cor[W_t^1,W_t^2] = \frac{Cov[W_t^1,W_t^2]}{\sqrt{V[W_t^1]} \sqrt{V[W_t^2]} } = \frac{\rho t}{t} = \rho.
$$

Comment: Thanks for this proof @Richard. Do you think my simulation code is ok? It seems ok. Another thing : I think your first equation is a "correlation" link between brownian motions $W_t^1$ and $W_t^2$, whereas my equation was a link between brownian motion *increments* $d W_t^1$ and $d W_t^2$. By summing the increments ([cumulative sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)), it seems that it would leed to the same formula as yours.  (of course when dealing with discretized brownian motion)

Comment: Hi, and no, I don't think so. You need the square-root because constant multiplicators enter variance with their square. and no matter whether we speak of increments or the processes it is variance and covariance that matters. Writing $W_t = W_t - W_0$ with $W_0 =0$ you can see that it does not matter whether we speak of increments or the process. In general we can write $W_t  = W_s + W_t-W_s$ and $W_t-W_s$ is independent of $W_s$ for $t>s$.

Comment: not that in the answer below the second parameter in $N(x,y)$ is the variance and not the volatility.

Comment: Oh yes sure, it was a mistake, I forgot the square root! Edited in my question. Now our 2 equations are equivalent (yours about brownian motion, mine about *increments* $d W_t$)

Comment: Yes, but in your second equastion you have a $Z$ which is just one random variable. MAybe you should put a $dZ_t$ there. Then if you integrate you have the same as I have.

Comment: Your're right @Richard, with $Z$, we could think we add always the same random variable. I replaced by $dZ_t$.

Answer (score 12):

Here is the **general approach** you can follow to generate two correlated random variables. Let's suppose, X and Y are two random variable, such that: 
$$X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$$
$$Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$$
and $$cor(X,Y)=\rho$$
Now consider: $y=bx + e_i$, where $x$ $(=\frac{X-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}$) and $y$  $(=\frac{Y-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}$) both follow standard normal distribution , such that $cor(x,y)=\rho. $ For standard normal variate, $b= \rho$. So we have:

## $$y=\rho x + e_i$$

## Now, here is the algorithm, you can follow:

1) Generate $n$ standard normal variate for $x$.

2) Since, $e_i \sim N(0, 1-\rho^2)$. So generates $n$ normal variate as $e_i$ from normal distribution with mean 0 and variance $1-\rho^2$.

3) Get $y=\rho x + e_i$.

4) Convert your standard normal numbers back to Normal (remember correlation is independent of change of origin and scale)

## R code for simulating correlated GBM:

```
corGBM <- function(n, r, t=1/365, plot=TRUE) {
#n is number of samples 
#r is correlation
#t is tick step
x <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd= 1)
se <- sqrt(1 - r^2) #standard deviation of error
e <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=se)
y <- r*x + e

X <- cumsum(x* sqrt(t))
Y <- cumsum(y* sqrt(t))
Max <- max(c(X,Y))
Min <- min(c(X,Y))

if(plot) {
plot(X, type="l", ylim=c(Min, Max))
lines(Y, col="blue")
}
return(cor(x,y))
}

#sample result
corGBM(10000,.85)
[1] 0.8523341
```

[image]

Comment: There are some problems in your R code I think : a) you aren't generating brownian motion but only increments. You have to cumsum them to get brownian motion. b) you define `r2` but you don't use it   c) even if both notations work, why writing `r ** 2` and then `r^2`?  d) you don't call the function `correlatedvalue`.   Can you include code to plot the two correlated brownian motions? *(More generally I think your method is more or less the same as the one I used in Python in my original post, but it's interesting to have it in R for learning purpose, thanks!)*

Comment: @Basj Thanks for your valuable inputs. I have added R code for simulating two geometric Brownian motion. I hope it would help you.